# Doble clic en menú responsive en movil iphone

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap, menú, iphone

Tengo un problema con un menú de una web, en los móviles que usan chrome, firefox funciona muy bien, pero al probarlo en safari en iphone el menú responsive de la web solo realiza las acciones al hacer doble clic.

Puede ver la web acá: http://svconstructions.com.ec/sv/

Esta usando bootstrap

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li><a href="index.php" >Inicio</a><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="qsomos.php" >Quienes Somos</a><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="proyectos.php" >Proyectos</a><span></span></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="servicios.php">Servicios </a><span>    </span>
                     </li>
        <li><a href="blog.php" >Blog</a><span></span></li>
        <li><a href="contactos.php" >Contactos</a><span></span></li>
```

**¿Alguien sabe porque no funciona en Safari de Iphone?**

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo de tu menu

Comment: He colocado el codigo del menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un *problema* conocido desde hace bastante tiempo (al menos desde 2010) y que se debe a cómo está diseñado el navegador para iPhone/iPad, y a cómo tiene definido el comportamiento para el `:hover`.

Es un problema interesante: mientras que la mayoría de los sistemas móviles ignoran el `:hover` (cuando se pasa el ratón por encima del elemento) porque realmente no hay un ratón, en iOS lo que se hace es que con el primer click se realiza la acción del `:hover` y con un segundo click se estará pulsando en el menú/enlace.

Una posible solución es añadir un controlador del evento `touchend` para que se realice la operación deseada con el enlace. El código (que no es mío y puedes encontrar en otros sitios online como [éste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426201/3695983) o [éste](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/solving-the-double-tap-issue-on-ios-devices)) sería algo así:

```
$('a').on('click touchend', function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var link = el.attr('href');
    window.location = link;
});
```

---

Otra posible alternativa (aunque sería más compleja y dependería de tu caso particular) sería asegurarte que ninguna acción que cambie el estilo de esos menús ocurra en el `:hover`: o bien eliminando todos los `:hover` de tus estilos; o bien hacer que no se cambie la imagen o el color de fondo, ni la opacidad, ni los bordes... en el `:hover` (por ejemplo, usando una hoja de estilos específica para dispositivos iOS).

Puedes leer más sobre esta opción en esta [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718702/3695983) o [este blog](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/) (ambos en inglés).

Comment: Voy a leer lo que me dices, y daré resultados.

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve el mismo problema y lo solucione colocando en el `<body>` de cada página `ontouchstart`
de la siguiente manera: `<body ontouchstart>` 
con eso los smatphone toman todos los :hover como activos (sin tomar ninguna modificacion en los botones) y al primer click funcionan todos los botones.
Espero te sea útil